# Add element to vector in nested tree structure

Tags: clojure

Jumping right in, better way of doing this:

```
(assoc-in 
    {:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [{:children []}]}]}]}]} 
    [:children 0 :children 0 :children 0 :children 0 :children 0] 
    :hello)
```

I want to insert `:hello` into deepest `:children` vector. Above I am doing it with  `assoc-in`.

Is there a better way than `assoc-in`?
Or, <strike>if</strike> when `assoc-in` is the only way, how would you handle `assoc-in`'s 2nd argument `[k & ks]`?

Also good to know if there it something that also works for inserting `:world` into and arbitrary `:children`'s vector... like the 3rd child or the 2nd child's 1st child.

Comment: Huh? You already can index into different spots in the vector; that index is what the `0` is.

Comment: If I understand you right: _yeah_. Looking to see if there is a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vector argument to `assoc-in` need not be a literal, so you can construct it as desired.

```
(def nested-map  
  {:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [{:children []}]}]}]}]})

(assoc-in nested-map (vec (take 10 (cycle [:children 0]))) :hello)
;=> {:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [:hello]}]}]}]}]}
```

Or for 3rd child of the 2nd child of the 1st child, construct a path like

```
(vec (interleave (repeat :children) [0 1 2]))
;=> [:children 0 :children 1 :children 2]
```

More generally you can use [zippers](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.zip/zipper) to arbitrarily move around the nested map, e.g. descend last child. The movement functions are can be composed, etc.

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip])

(def z (zip/zipper map? :children #(assoc % :children (vec %2)) nested-map))

(-> (ffirst (filter (comp zip/end? second)  ; find last
                    (partition 2 1 (iterate zip/next z)))) 
    (zip/edit (constantly :hello)) ; change to :hello
    zip/root) ; bubble up changes

;=> {:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [:hello]}]}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Especially for `interleave + repeat` and the references to zippers.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `clojure.walk` for this

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as w])

(def nested-map  
  {:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [{:children []}]}]}]}]})

(w/postwalk (fn [node] (if (and (vector? node) (empty? node))
                         (conj node :hello)
                         node))
            nested-map)
=> {:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [{:children [:hello]}]}]}]}]}
```